# How to take snap shot of a video using action script 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an swf player with a button and an FLVPlayback component. I have to save the current key frame of the video when I click the button. How can I achieve this in action script 3.0

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `draw` method of `BitmapData` class. Sample code could look like this:

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(vidWidth, vidHeight);

bd.draw(yourFLVPlaybackInstance);
//or you may use an instance of Video from FLVPlayer

//now you can assign your bitmapData to a Bitmap
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
```

Comment: Keep in mind the security rules.  If you attempt to draw content from another domain you'll get a SecurityError.  From the docs, "The source object and (in the case of a Sprite or MovieClip object) all of its child objects do not come from the same domain as the caller, or are not in a content that is accessible to the caller by having called the Security.allowDomain() method. This restriction does not apply to AIR content in the application security sandbox. "

Comment: I have managed to get the Bitmap of the movie. But how can I save that as an image into a physical location?

Comment: What do you mean by 'physical location'? On the server? On the user's hard drive? In both cases you would need to use JPEGEncoder (or PNGEncoder) to convert your Bitmap into a standard image file.